# How to make typescript find type annotations from `.d.ts` files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I can't make typescript to find type annotations from `.d.ts` files.
here is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "components/*": [
                "src/components/*"
            ],
            "constants/*": [
                "src/constants/*"
            ],
            "services/*": [
                "src/services/*"
            ],
            "reducers/*": [
                "src/reducers/*"
            ],
            "selectors/*": [
                "src/selectors/*"
            ],
            "types/*": [
                "src/types/*"
            ],
            "pages/*": [
                "src/screens/*"
            ],
        },
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "react-native",
        "noEmit": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./src/types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "babel.config.js",
        "metro.config.js",
        "jest.config.js"
    ]
}
```

Also here is an example of the usage. This is a util function that is inside `src/services/redux/utils.ts`.

```
export function unpack<T extends Record<string, unknown> | []>(dataState: IDataState<T>, defaultState = {}) {
  if (dataState) {
    const isBusy = dataState.status === 1;
    const payload = dataState.payload ? dataState.payload : defaultState;

    return [payload as T, isBusy, dataState.error || null];
  }

  return [defaultState as T, false, null];
}
```

And here is the type declaration inside the `types.d.ts` file.

```
interface IDataState<T> {
  dateReceived?: number;
  dateRequested?: number;
  error?: Error;
  payload: T | Record<string, unknown>;
  requestGuid: string;
  status: number;
}
```

And typescript throws an error

> Cannot find name 'IDataState'

I have created `types.d.ts`inside `src/services` and trying to access those types from the same directory.
I have already investigated some other questions on `Stackoverflow` but none of them was an answer to my problem.
What should I add to my config?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify all the necessary files in the typeRoots compiler option https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots

Comment: It doesn't help. I can only use them if import them.But as I know, should be able to use them without importing.

Comment: can you provide an example of the actual declarations and how you use them?

Comment: you must be misunderstanding what `.d.ts` files are actually for. Check https://medium.com/jspoint/typescript-type-declaration-files-4b29077c43 or some other articles

Comment: I have followed the instructions in that article, and again no result. Anyway thanks for your help.